# sorting array by certain value in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, reverse

if i have an array like:

```
var myArray = []

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 myArray.unshift({
  myString: 'string'+ i +'',
  myValue: i;
 });
}
```

and want to sort it by the 'myValue' values. like

```
myArray.myValue.sort (function(a, b){return a-b});
```

however, this is not working.

Comment: can you share the sample input and output?

Comment: Something like this? `myArray.sort(function a, b) { return a.myValue - b.myValue})`

Comment: He only wants to sort one particular property of the objects in the array and leave the other properties untouched - he does not want to sort the entire array *by* some property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you wish to sort by **myValue**?

```
myArray.sort(function a, b) { 

  return a.myValue - b.myValue;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort only one object property (while leaving the rest untouched), what you will have to do is make a copy of that specific property of each item in the array, sort that, and then copy the properties back over:

```
// make a copy of the myValues into a new array containing just those
var myValueArray = myArray.map(function(item) { return item.myValue; });
// sort just the myValues in the copy 
myValueArray.sort();
// copy the sorted myValues back
myValueArray.forEach(function(item, index){ myArray[index].myValue = item; });
```